# selectable + slider: dont work 'click' inside

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Using [selectable](http://jqueryui.com/selectable/) and [slider](http://jqueryui.com/slider/#side-scroll), jquery click function dont work inside these widgets.

```
$("span.span1").click(function(event){              // dont work inside my selectable block
//$("span.span1").mouseenter(function(event) {      // work! inside 
//$("span.span1").mousedown(function(event) {       // work! inside
    console.log("small img");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nywuctuk/tm8yhoz7/3/

Can i do it avaliable somehow? May be try clear this event from outside events...
p.s. Even MOUSEDOWN work well!! (i think i will use it)
p.s.2 Forgot say about slider. Its using too.

Comment: Can you clarify the issue a bit? Also what browser are you using for this issue?

Comment: Your fiddle does not show your use of .selectable();

Comment: lsal niro - I trying use click function inside selectable block and nothing;  last Chrome.  Brino - just belieave me :)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/tm8yhoz7/4/  It looks to be working but -only- if you click on the text, not the whitespace of the selectable, as your span only exists in a small piece of your selectable space.  You'll probably need to change your selector, or increase the size of your span, if you want it to happen regardless of where they click on the selectable.

Comment: Try binding on $("span.span1").parent() (though that didn't seem to work in the fiddle)

Comment: Taplar - selector is good becouse of mouseenter work well; and i tried another - didnt work.  Taplar - i need this part of full image...

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `z-index:999` style to `ul > li > span`, it might help

Comment: I tried '10' - didnt help. But if it work well without z-index in my example why it will help there? And if try use it then i should set z-index for all blocks near... its hard.